# Questions regarding image slider code in css

Tags: css, web, frontend

link to image slider - https://codepen.io/huijing/pen/GvNLJm

question regarding above slider :
How is  *hidden* animation working ? What is the point of going from `z-index: 2;` to `z-index: 2;` ?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul{
list-style:none;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 0;
  }
  .thumbnails li {
    flex: auto;
  }
  .thumbnails a {
    display: block;
  }
  .thumbnails img {
    width: 30vmin;
    height: 20vmin;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
  }

.slides {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  }
  .slides li {
    width: 75vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .slides img {
    height: 100vmin;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
  }

.slides li:target {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.slides li:not(:target) {
  -webkit-animation: hidden 1s 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes hidden {
  0% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="slides">
  <li id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li id="slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li id="slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li id="slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  <li id="slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
      <a href="#slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to do the same thing in x-direction also - https://codepen.io/GauravSKoshyari/pen/ZEMpXWZ

It is working in case of left to right slider , but if i do changes in *slide* animation to make it right to left , as shown below

```
@keyframes slide {
0% {
    transform: translateX(+100%);
}

100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

}

IT IS NOT WORKING

Comment: I made a snippet of your code and formatted it to clearly show the HTML has an issue. No starting `<ul>`tag exists

Comment: The purpose of using the animation versus just setting the `z-index` value directly is to preserve the stacking order following the animation.  Using the same value for both the 0% and 100% in the keyframes prevents any flicker.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss , if u go to codepen , starting <ul> tag is there . I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: @jme , i understand what u r saying , but still don't know how it is working actually(from inside) . Also pls check the edit .